# I want to get domain details from “Entity” calling Azure API

Tags: php, azure, api, curl, azure-active-directory

I want to get domain details from “Entity” calling Azure API.

I used :

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/<--tid-->/oauth2/v2.0/authorize --> For
>   authorization
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/<--tid-->/oauth2/v2.0/token   --> For
>   Token
>
> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/  --> Using token and api I got userdata.

Now I need domain details of perticular user, Please help me.

Here I use curl call to get userdata. 
My code :

```
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1 , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);      
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token));
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/');
$result1 = curl_exec($ch1);
```

I go Json response :

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
  "businessPhones": [],
  "displayName": "<displayName>",
  "givenName": "<givenName>",
  "jobTitle": "<jobTitle>",
  "mail": "<mail_id>",
  "mobilePhone": "<mobilePhone>",
  "preferredLanguage": null,
  "surname": "<surname>",
  "userPrincipalName": "<userPrincipalName>",
  "id": "<some_id>"
}
```

Is there Any way to get domain details inside this response or I have to call another API for it

Comment: What do domain details refer to?

Comment: User assign to  particular domain  . I may get details from entity. But how to claim entity using api call

Comment: Is `onPremisesDomainName` value what you need?

Comment: You can find all the properties of the user by using beta version api. https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me. If you need some specific properties, you can use $select like this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=displayName,onPremisesDomainName `

Comment: Ok , I can get all details at ` https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` . Is It possible ??

Comment: I need onPremisesDomainName

Comment: For v1.0 version, you need to add $select to display the properties you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $select to get `onPremisesDomainName` property like this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=displayName,onPremisesDomainName
```

Refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for more details.